# The PID of the prev. command in the backgrounded pipeline

Tags: linux, shell

I have a script fragment:

```
MyCoolCommand 2>&1 | tail -n 256 > "report.out" &
cool_pid=$!  # FIXME
```

It has a bug - `cool_pid` is the PID of `tail`. The pipeline is running in background. How to save in the `cool_pid` the PID of `MyCoolCommand`? The shell is /bin/sh. If it's impossible with old plain /bin/sh, I am ready to switch to Bash if there is a way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bash you can use process substitution:

```bash
MyCoolCommand > >(tail -n 256 > report.out) 2>&1 &
cool_pid=$!
```

Data will flow from `MyCoolCommand` to `tail` like in your original command, but `$!` will be what you want.

Notes:

- [`2>&1` needs to be after `>`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055).
- The shell will consider the job done just after `MyCoolCommand` exits, while [`tail` may still be running](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/351785/108618). If your script at some point `wait`s for the job and then processes `report.out` further, keep in mind the file may not be ready yet. For comparison: your `MyCoolCommand | tail … &` is considered done after *both* processes exit.

---

You can solve the problem in plain `sh`, but this requires manual plumbing:

```sh
mkfifo myfifo
<myfifo tail -n 256 >report.out &
MyCoolCommand >myfifo 2>&1 &
cool_pid=$!
rm myfifo
```

Notes:

- Removing the fifo when it's still in use is safe. The programs will keep using it, despite the fact it's unlinked from the directory. The OS will truly destroy the fifo only when it's no longer in use. A new file named `myfifo` (if ever created) will have nothing to do with the old one (except the name), even if the old one is still in use.
- If a file named `myfifo` is already in the current working directory (because another instance of the script runs in parallel; or for whatever reason) and maybe in use, then the script may misbehave. The right thing to do is to create a temporary directory with `mktemp -d` and place a fifo there. `mktemp` is not portable.
- In this method you can save the PID of `MyCoolCommand` *and* independently the PID of `tail`.